# PostgreSQL merge rows versioned by date ranges with priority

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, overlap, date-range

Currently I am working on staff management system that allows to setup subordinate relations between two positions (e.g. Software Engineer is a subordinate of Team Lead).
In database schema it looks like:

```sql
position_managers (position_id, manager_id, start_date, end_date)
-- The start_date and end_date are the date range during which the relationship is valid 

team_lead, ceo, 2021-01-01, 9999-12-31
software_engineer, team_lead, 2021-01-01, 2021-12-31
```

But currently I need to implement the second data source (that comes from foreign system) which will override subordinate relations:

```sql
position_overridden_managers (position_id, manager_id, start_date, end_date) 
software_engineer, ceo, 2021-01-01, 2021-06-20
software_engineer, hr, 2021-06-25, 2021-08-20
```

I want to select all rows from position_managers and position_overridden_managers and combine them into one result set, respecting the overridden rules.

```
position_id, manager_id, start_date, end_date
team_lead, ceo, 2021-01-01, 9999-12-31

software_engineer, ceo, 2021-01-01, 2021-06-20
software_engineer, team_lead, 2021-06-21, 2021-06-24
software_engineer, hr, 2021-06-25, 2021-08-20
software_engineer, team_lead, 2021-08-21, 2021-12-31
```

**UPD**: I found this blog post - https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/range-types-recursion-how-to-search-availability-with-postgresql

But the SQL in the blog post was a bit buggy and I found a fix for this blog post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142229/2585154

I adapted this solution for my purpose: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a598b9cc892746a0a6c20b1deb473357

Is this the best way to achieve the desired result?

**UPD2**: Found solution is also buggy. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3aad6bb0fabe1ffd580ec03126c92848

It makes duplicate row on following data-set:

```sql
-- managers
(1, 'first', '2017-09-01'::date, '2018-10-14'::date),
(1, 'second', '2018-10-15'::date, '2019-10-31'::date),
(1, 'third', '2019-11-01'::date, '9999-12-31'::date)

-- override
(1, 'override', '2021-01-01'::date, '9999-12-31'::date)
```

Output is:

```
position_id     manager     start_date  end_date
1               first       2017-09-01  2018-10-14
1               second      2018-10-15  2019-10-31
1               third       2019-11-01  2020-12-31
-- incorrect duplicate below
1               third       2019-11-01  9999-12-31
1               override    2021-01-01  9999-12-31
```

**UPD3**: Found another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/23165263/2585154 and adapted for myself.
It works OK on different data sets:

1. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66207fd1f9d6dfd7d1fe0897ddbcc89b
2. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af733c0e2806a689a61092875820d2c6

Comment: Note: you can set end_date to `infinity` instead of `9999-12-31` And: your question is unclear. Please clarify your intentions.

Comment: @wildplasser look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145504/splitting-overlapping-dates-in-sql that is what exactly I trying to do